# Azure DevOps Unit Test Cover with Opencover ignore [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage] attribute

Tags: unit-testing, azure-devops, sonarqube

i try to implement an azure pipeline that execute a test and upload the coverage result in Sonarqube.

I succesfully implement the pipeline, but when i try to upload to sonarqube the result of coverage analisys in opencover format, the result is different from the cobertura because the opencover ignore the [ExcludeFromCodeCoverage] attribute.

this is my pipeline code

```
    - task: DotNetCoreCLI@2
  displayName: Unit Test Execution
  inputs:
    command: 'test'
    projects: ${{parameters.unitTestProjects}}
    arguments: '--collect "XPlat Code Coverage;Format=cobertura,opencover,Coverlet"'

- task: PublishCodeCoverageResults@1
  inputs:
    codeCoverageTool: 'Cobertura' # 'Cobertura' | 'JaCoCo'. Required. Code coverage tool. Default: JaCoCo.
    summaryFileLocation: $(Agent.TempDirectory)/*/coverage.cobertura.xml
```

there is a argument to tell to exclude the class/assembly with this attribute?

Thanks in advance